# Code to Disable PDF Viewer does not work anymore

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

The following code used to successfully disable the internal Chrome PDF Viewer. Not anymore starting chromedriver 76.

```
    chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True})
driver  = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

What changed? And how can I disable the internal PDF viewer?

Note that I'm using **Python**

Comment: chromePrefs.put("plugins.always_open_pdf_externally", true);  try this

Comment: I think I'm already doing that. I've now added the complete to the OP.

Did you mean something else?